# System.NullReferenceException Not Being Caught in First Try/Catch Block

Tags: c#, .net, exception, try-catch

I have a C# Console app that starts in 'static int Main(string[] args)', creates an instance of 'EventRecievedProcessor' class and then calls a method on the instance:

```
static int Main(string[] args)
{
    try
    {
        EventRecievedProcessor proc = new EventRecievedProcessor

        if (!proc.Processs())
        {
            Console.Write(Type + "  processing failed.  Please check logs for more information.");
            Log.Error("Failed to process s");
            return (int)RETURNCODES.INTERNALAPPERROR;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // This is where the System.NullReferenceException from GetLatestEventInfo is currently being caught

        Console.WriteLine("Exception message: " + ex.Message);
        Console.WriteLine("Exception stack trace: " + ex.StackTrace);

        Log.Fatal("An exception has been thrown. Message: " + ex.Message, ex);

        return (int)RETURNCODES.INTERNALAPPERROR;
    }
}
```

The instance of 'EventRecievedProcessor' grabs a collection of records and does a foreach  over it. It calls a static method (GetLatestEventInfo) on the 'Event' class for each record in the collection:

```
public class EventRecievedProcessor
{

    public bool Processs()
    { 
        List<Event> events = DAL.GetEvents;

        foreach (Event e in events)
       {
            try
            {
                EventInfo lastEvent = Eventhistory.GetLatestEventInfo(e);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // Log exception and continue processing in foreach loop

                // This is where I want to catch the NullReferenceException from GetLatestEventInfo

                Log.DebugFormat("Error with eventid " + e.EventID);
                Log.Error(ex);
            }
        } 

        return true;
    }
}
```

When the follwoing method is called, a System.NullReferenceException is thrown:

```
public class EventHistory
{

    public static EventInfo GetLatestEventInfo(int customerCode, string premiscode)
    {

        EventInfo info = new EventInfo();

        // Do some work here...
        // This is where the NullReferenceException is being generated.

        return info; 

    }
}
```

When the NullReferenceException is thrown here, I would expect the catch block in the foreach loop to catch it, log it, and then return control to the foreach loop to continue processing. Instead, the exception is being caught in the top level 'Main' method, which means the app aborts and the remaining records are not processed.

I'm at loss as to how/why the exception bypasses the first catch block. Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong here?

Adding the stack trace:

System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at EventProcessor.EventHistory.GetLatestEventInfo(Event e) in C:\Dev\release6.01.100\Events\EventProcessor\EventProcessor\EventHistory.cs:line 65
   at EventProcessor.Processors.EventProcessor.Process() in C:\Dev\release6.01.100\Events\EventProcessor\EventProcessor\Processors\EventProcessor.cs:line 32
   at EventProcessor.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Dev\release6.01.100\Events\EventProcessor\EventProcessor\Program.cs:line 132

Sorry if I've munched some of the names. This is work code, so I tried to change it up a little to avoid any privacy conflicts.

Comment: Could you show us the stack-trace from when the exception is shown?

Comment: You're calling `Event.GetLatestEventInfo` static method, and you show us the source for `EventHistory.GetLatestEventInfo` (from other class). Is this typo or should it be like that?

Comment: Did you verify that the call to GetLatestEventInfo raises the exception (by looking at the stacktrace?). Maybe DAL.GetEvents calls GetlatestEventInfo as well?

Comment: just to clarify - I may clouded the issue by changing the names of the objects and methods being used. I was sloppy in failing to rename everything accurately and failing to update the method signatures. Looking at it from high-level though, the stack trace shows the exception being generated in the EventHistory (line 65), bubbling up the stack to the calling code at line 32 of EventRecievedProcessor.Processs, and finally to the top level caller at line 132 of EventProcessor.Main.

Comment: You need to show us the code in your catch blocks.

Comment: I added the catch block code and fixed some typos. Thanks.

Comment: Ha! I'm an ass. Lutz's .NET Reflector shows that the code that is in production differs from that in SVN. In production, the EventRecievedProcessor doesn't have the Try/Catch nested in the foreach. Sorry for the wasted time - I should have verified that the code I was looking at matched the code I was troubleshooting before posting. Thanks to all that contributed.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't bypass anything. Look closely at your stack trace.

Try using `Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());`.

You'll see that the exception is not being thrown from where you thought it was.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback Jon. Could you expand on your point a little? The stack trace identifies EventHistory.GetLatestEventInfo() as the source of the exception.

Comment: The source of the exception is _inside_ of `EventHistory.GetLatestEventInfo()`, where you do not have a try/catch block.

Comment: Correct. So my expectation was that the exception would bubble up to the calling code, which is in a try/catch block?

Answer (score 1):

This simply isn't the case and here's the proof:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        // no need of try/catch here as exceptions won't propagate to here
        Looper();
    }

    static void Looper()
    {
        int processedRecords = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            try
            {
                Thrower(i);
                processedRecords++;
            }
            catch (NullReferenceException ex)
            { }
        }
        // prints 5 as expected
        Console.WriteLine("processed {0} records", processedRecords);
    }

    static void Thrower(int i)
    {
        if (i % 2 == 0)
        {
            throw new NullReferenceException();
        }
    }
}
```